# How can I input the values of 2 lists into a math equation

Tags: python, list, math

I have two lists, probability[] and miss[]

I need to plug my 2 lists into a formula. `severity = probability* 100,000 / miss`

When I print(probability), I get `0.000001731517 0 0 0` and when I print(miss), I get `6954 12507 3621 10440`

This is my attempt at plugging them into the formula.

```
severity=[]
for i in range(len(severity)):
    severity[i] = (probability[i]*100000/miss[i])
    print(severity[i])
```

What am I doing wrong? it doesn't even make it into the for loop

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is empty, so when you run the for loop, it is equivalent to `for i in range(0)`, which means it does not make it into the for loop.

You should do

```
severity=[]
for i in range(len(probability)):
    severity.append(probability[i]*100000/miss[i])
    print(severity[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy instead and then you don't need a for loop:

```
import numpy as np
severity = np.array(probability)*100000/np.array(miss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension you can write

```py
severity = [p*100_000/m for p,m in zip(probability, miss)]
```